# Applet Application blocked for security

Tags: java, security, applet, lwjgl

Applet code inside HTML file:

```
<APPLET code="org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader" archive="lwjgl_util_applet.jar" codebase="." width="800" height="600">

<param name="al_title" value="Game">

<param name="al_main" value="org.newdawn.slick.AppletGameContainer">
<param name="game" value="me.zarkopafilis.shitpong.Main">

<param name="al_jars" value="Game.jar, lwjgl.jar, slick.jar">

<!-- signed jars containing the native files for each pathform --> 
<param name="al_windows" value="windows_natives.jar">
<param name="al_linux" value="linux_natives.jar">
<param name="al_mac" value="macosx_natives.jar">
<param name="al_solaris" value="solaris_natives.jar">

<param name="separate_jvm" value="true">
```

My Game.jar is self-signed correctly.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried to deploy a simple slick pong game as an applet.

Answer (score 1):

You say your jar is self-signed correctly. If that means that you used a self-signed certificate to sign your jar, then that might be the problem. Applets signed with a self-signed certificate are blocked. So I advise you to get a code signing certificate issued by some common CA and sign your using that certificate.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be multiple issues that may cause this. All seem to have something to do with the jar-signing of the LWJGL jars.

There is a discussion about this [in the LWJGL forum](http://lwjgl.org/forum/index.php/topic,5315.0.html)